# Power BI - Show top 5 values in bar chart

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, powerbi-desktop

I want to show the top 5 records in a bar chart.

I have done the following:
Added a visual level filter. Filter type: Top N, Show Items: Top 5.

But this does not solve my problem.

Any help?

[image: picture]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ze3hbxguijaqm05/test_test_4.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a field to "By value". So just add "Name_NAME1" and it works.

Comment: i already add  NAME_NAME1 in value... and it already checked mark so when i click on that this is going to uncheck ..